# forward image from private channel to telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want to receive image from private channel into my bot. I use ForwardMessageAsync but it don't work. my bot is administrator in private channel.Please help me. 
Thanks a million.

```
Splatform.ForwardMessageAsync(chat_id, from_chat_id, message_id);
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I don't receive error. It don't work.. Does the image which is in private channel have message id?